# Forecast package in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, forecasting, forecast-combination

I have one question which is maybe very simple.
So my question is does models from forecast package in R (e.g auto.arima,ets,tbats,nnetar etc) are machine learning models or not?

Comment: Could you tell us what, in your mind, distinguishes a "machine learning" model from other statistical models?

Comment: @whuber Usually in literature you can find that machine learning models are e.g random forest,neural network etc.So this models are little bit diffrent then clasical statistical method like arima,exponential smoothing etc.So for taht reason I ask this question.